# I'm trying to think of a new domain name, what are words/prefixes/suffixes that convey the same essense as "wiki"?

Tags: domains

I'm trying to think of a new domain name, what are words/prefixes/suffixes that convey the same essense as "wiki"?

I want to convey that it's a site where everyone collaborates together to make the pages.

Comment: Just don't use book, Facebook lawyers will come after you (recent news story).

Comment: @user1725 - Thank goodness nobody uses cook books!

Comment: This is a discussion, hence made community wiki.

Answer (score 2):

From the phrases:

- "All change please"
- "One small step for man, one giant leap for mankind"
- "Many hands make light work"

To the words:

- [book](http://thesaurus.com/browse/book)
- [change](http://thesaurus.com/browse/change)
- [encyclopedia](http://thesaurus.com/browse/encyclopedia)

To the (available) domain names:

- www.amorphesaurus.com from amorphous and thesaurus (sounds a bit like a dinosaur and thesaurus is just poor)
- www.amorphmana.co from amorphous and almanac
- www.refinelopedia.com from refinement and encyclopedia

If its less about the conventional wiki and more about the development of pages then:

- www.revdevpages.com from revised, developed pages

Or more tastefully:

- www.varifolio.com from variation and folio
- www.diversiopus.com from diversity and opus

Answer (score 1):

*board (as in whiteboard, sketchboard, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Some less traditional ideas:

- storm (as in brainstorm)
- collect
- cloud

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head:

- docs
- notes

Answer (score 0):

Something ending with the sound of "democracy" eg, knolocracy. (google Knol + democracy).

Since you were somewhat vague in what the site is specific to:
Webocracy.